# How does one autoscale web dynos on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, scalability

With Heroku, how does one **AUTO** scale up in terms of web dynos when it is needed? Say we get a surge of 100 concurrent users every 2-3 minutes. If our app is stuck on 5-6 web dynos. We are screwed.

Second, I wouldn't be able to monitor traffic 24 hours to determine whether a scale up or down is required.

So far, I've seen http://hirefireapp.com/ and http://www.heroscale.com/ 
Any suggestions about these two?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason heroku don't do this natively is that it's an incredibly complex problem to solve.

For instance, imagine your scenario above, you suddenly start seeing a queue forming and want to ramp the dynos.  You crank on ten more.  However, it's not a dyno problem, your database is running slow, so now you've got more dynos all sat waiting for the database which now has even more demand placed on it.

Whilst there are auto-scaling products out there, I've not tried any of them, and fully believe that at the moment only a human can make the correct call on scaling.  Your mileage may vary.

I have found in the past that setting the resources to an expected usage level (which may be above the current usage) tends to work best, excluding massive traffic influx (such as being on Hacker News etc)

Comment: Hmmm, but what happens if you do get hit by Hacker News and no one is in the office to manually scale up? Wouldn't that cause request timeouts popping all over the place / putting the app semi-offline (500 error)?

Comment: Unfortunately, that answer is going to be different for every single application and the signature it has on the hardware that it runs on.

Comment: Well, if an app receives 20-30x more hits due to a traffic influx. I'm pretty sure some page views won't go through. i.e. not enough web handlers to go around. I believe Heroku has a request timeout of 55 seconds, before it terminates the connection

Comment: 30 seconds to return a response.  The problem is that you can only tell you have high traffic via the queue length, and adding dynos might not solve that.

Comment: Surely there must be other ways to detect what's happening with traffic.  I'm no expert but off the top of my head you could increment some sort of counter in a key-value store with each request.  Or have a different counter for each minute and compare minutes to average.

Comment: It's been 2 years since this answer, is it still relevant? I see that Heroku now has an [add-on for auto-scaling dynos](https://addons.heroku.com/marketplace/adept-scale). Do you still believe that only a human can make the correct calls on scaling?

Comment: Yes.  And FWIW auto-scaling is only really a problem for those running smaller apps and on a cost consious basis.

Comment: Good answer. Do you know any monitoring tools which could email you if the queue lenght exceed a fixed size ? (similar to apdex on newrelic).

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but wanted to add that I use Librato's counters as key-value store as Luke pointed out. This allows us to anticipate the need for scaling. I also just read that HireFire can be tied to New Relic and scale based on RPM, so I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 25):

I built [HireFire](https://www.hirefire.io) and would like to share some up-to-date information:

HireFire autoscales both your web- and worker dynos using our dyno managers. We currently support the following metric sources:

- HireFire (Job Queue) | Worker Dynos
- Heroku Logplex (Response Time) | Web Dynos
- Heroku Logplex (Connect Time) | Web Dynos
- Heroku Logplex (Queue Time) | Web Dynos
- Heroku Logplex (Requests Per Minute) | Web Dynos
- Heroku Logplex (CPU Load) | Web/Worker Dynos
- NewRelic (Apdex) | Web Dynos
- NewRelic (Response Time) | Web Dynos
- NewRelic (Requests Per Minute) | Web Dynos

---

**HireFire (Job Queue)**

Autoscales your worker-based dyno based on the queue size of your jobs. Integration for Ruby and Python applications can be done easily using a 1st or 3rd party library. Any other language and/or framework can be integrated easily without a library as well.

You're able to configure any number of dyno managers for a given application at no extra cost, meaning that you're not limited to a single "worker" entry in your Procfile. This (optionally) allows you to schedule work more efficiently by having for example one Procfile entry per queue and having HireFire scale each individual queue independently.

---

**Heroku Logplex**

The Logplex (Logdrain) strategy allows HireFire to consume your logs in order to parse Heroku-emitted metric data which we then use to autoscale. Metrics include Response Time, Connect Time and Load. In addition to that we support Queue Time which can easily be added by installing our library. Or, you can write the minimal amount of code yourself to push the necessary data to the logdrain.

This abstract approach (excluding Queue Time) requires no code changes and works with any language/framework. Just setup a Logdrain via de Heroku CLI and you're set.

For metric aggregation, you can choose between average and (any) percentile.

---

**New Relic**

We integrate with New Relic. If you're already using it you can hook it up to HireFire and use their metrics (apdex, response time and rpm) to autoscale your web dynos.

---

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to get in touch!

Comment: I can second hirefire. It's working rather well for us at www.streetbank.com.

Comment: It tests for latency, and job queue length once a minute and scales up or down appropriately. Obviously you still need a human involved because there's more to scaling than dynos, but so far it's doing a very good job of handling lumpy traffic.

Answer (score 12):

A lot of my friends in the Rails community use [Rails Autoscale](https://railsautoscale.com/) for autoscaling on Heroku. Here's how it works:

> Rails Autoscale provides a tiny Rack middleware that captures this timing and periodically reports it back to the Rails Autoscale service. This is similar to how New Relic works at a fraction of the size.

The autoscaling that Heroku provides natively is only available on their Performance tier (which starts at $250 / month per dyno). If you're using the Hobby or Standard plans, you'll need to find a 3rd party solution.

One thing I like about Rails Autoscale is it scales your app up and down automatically, based on request queueing.

It's a nice feature, especially for peace of mind. If you're sleeping, and get a traffic spike, you can't manually adjust the number of dynos. Having a tool that can scale up automatically is nice insurance.

Answer (score 11):

Heroku just launched a new addon that does auto scaling. Web dynos only right now though.

Check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075781/484689

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a Heroku auto scaling engine called Heroku Vector. It allows you to scale web and sidekiq dynos based on the volume of traffic you receive (instead of waiting for latencies in response time):

https://github.com/wpeterson/heroku-vector

You can run it as a stand-alone dyno process.

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2017, Heroku formally supports autoscaling.

> Autoscaling is easy to set up and use, and it recommends a p95
>   threshold based on your app’s past 24 hours of response times.
>   Response-based autoscaling ensures that your web dyno formation is
>   always sized for optimal efficiency, while capping your costs based on
>   limits you set. Autoscaling is currently included at no additional
>   cost for apps using Performance and Private web dynos.

Here are the docs:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling#autoscaling

Here is the announcement: https://blog.heroku.com/heroku-autoscaling